# Translating a mongo query with dates into pure JSON

Tags: json, mongodb, date, datetime

I need to store and transfer some mongodb queries built in javascript for later execution in a back-end written in *go* language.

A few of these queries involve comparison with dates. In mongodb's shell, there is a specific format for performing queries with dates; with the `ISODate` construct.

Is it possible to have a different construct, that is nicely translatable in pure JSON so that different systems that use mongodb can run the same query in a compatible way?

I already tried several queries that do not involve using special constructs such as `ISODate` or JavaScript's native `Date` object, but had not luck with it.

I also tried [MongoDB Extended JSON](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/mongodb-extended-json/) as in: `db.userStats.find({'Tmin': {$gt: { $date: '1999-12-31T23:00:00.000Z'} }})`, but it did not work.

Any ideas?

thanks!

Comment: Have you looked at using [MongoDB Extended JSON](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/mongodb-extended-json/)?

Comment: I did, but when I tried `db.userStats.find({'Tmin': {$gt: { $date: '1999-12-31T23:00:00.000Z'} }})`, it just did not work. No results, from mongo shell

Comment: Why not store and compare as millis since unix epoch ?

Comment: @francescostablum That's right, outside of some of the MongoDB tools you can't use it directly, so you'd need to do some translation back into the native type for where you're executing it.

Comment: @S.D. I tried that, in the form `{$gt : 0}`, which should get everything after the epoch (theoretically). But it does not work. Is this what you meant?

Comment: @JohnnyHK: the `$date` trick does not work even within the MongoDB shell

Comment: @francescostablum That's correct. It's just a standardized JSON format you can use for your situation.

Comment: @JohnnyHK: even worse, the `$date` trick does not work even in *node.js*. But what do you mean when you say *That's correct*? It's not working!

Comment: @francescostablum :) You're reading too much into my suggestion.  It's _just_ a format you can use to store and transfer your queries.  You can't use it to directly execute queries.

Comment: @JohnnyHK: hmm, so does this imply that there should be a "decoder" function in most mongo implementations?

Comment: MongoDB drivers handle serialisation between native objects and BSON (to exchange queries/commands from the server). There isn't a common "JSON interchange" format supported by all drivers, but as suggested in several comments you could use MongoDB Extended JSON as a basis for this. You should consider the `mongo` shell as another driver/interface: it does not support Extended JSON (as at MongoDB 2.6). There is a [`mongodb-extended-json`](https://www.npmjs.org/package/mongodb-extended-json) package for NodeJS; it looks like someone (maybe you?) has yet to write a package for use with Go ;-).

Comment: FYI, you might want to watch/upvote [SERVER-6813: Shell support for Extended JSON](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-6813). This doesn't directly help your application use case, but it could be useful to work with Extended JSON in the `mongo` shell.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a standard driver- or client-independent way to write down MongoDB queries in a human friendly form. Extended JSON is the "closest" thing but it's not understood by drivers. The best option is to cook up a format that works for your applications.